# I am trying to convert DIV to Image without HTML2CANVAS

Tags: magento-1.9, php, convert

I am recently trying to convert **html to image** in **magento 1.9.2.4**. so i have used **Html2canvas.js**. But It **conflict with Magento Default prototype.js**. So now i need to convert div to image without canvas. any idea about this.

Comment: Try [wkhtmltoimage](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. but ihave no idea about wkhtmltoimage

Comment: then check out the link